# Keys with maximum value in Python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to find the keys with maximum values. I try to uses other's code but it is just printed 1 key 'C'. However, my dictionary has 2 keys with the same maximum value.

```
my_dict = {'A':4,'B':10,'C':87,'D':87}
maximum = max(mydict, key=mydict.get)
print(maximum, mydict[maximum])
```

How can I get both C,D and append them to a list?

Comment: but, instead of `iteritems()` use `items()`.